# MPAndroidChart X Axis and Y Axis values changes

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

In my application, I need to display bar graphs. For that I am using MPAndroidChart library. Displayed the graph very well by using the following code.

This is the line added in gradle file

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
```

This is the activity

```
    public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        BarChart barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new BarEntry(38f, 0));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(52f, 1));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(65f, 2));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(30f, 3));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(85f, 4));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(19f, 5));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(75f, 6));
        
        BarDataSet bardataset = new BarDataSet(entries, " ");
        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("Mon");
        labels.add("Tue");
        labels.add("Wed");
        labels.add("Thus");
        labels.add("Fri");
        labels.add("Sat");
        labels.add("Sun");

        BarData data = new BarData(labels, bardataset);
        barChart.setData(data); // set the data and list of lables into chart

        bardataset.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
        bardataset.setColor(Color.rgb(102, 178, 255));

    }

    public class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the bellow out put.

[image]

But in my application, I need to display Y-Axis values are like this 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 ,35 instaed of 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and X-axis values (Mon, Tue, Wed, ....) should display bottom of the screen.
How to do these two changes.

Thanks... In advance

Answer (score 0):

For displaying X Axis values in bottom.

```
barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```